# Editing a text file by doing math operation inside the file

Tags: python, text-files, text-editor

I have a text file (text.txt) like this:

```
50  10  15  20  25
40  30  35  40  45
30  50  55  60  65
```

I have edited this file as below:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('text.txt')]
output = open('a.txt', 'w')

for line in lines:
    line = line.split()

    output.write('Values({},{},{},{},{});\n'.format(line[0], line[1], 
line[2], line[3], line[4]))

output.close()
```

Here is the new text file:

```
Values(50,10,15,20,25);
Values(40,30,35,40,45);
Values(30,50,55,60,65);
```

Now I want to edit the file (the original text.txt) by doing math operation on its components in a way that:

1. I want to subtract 10 from  all of the components in the first
   column
2. I want to subtract 1 from all of the components in the rest of the
   columns

To be more specific I am looking at this:

```
Values(40,9,14,19,24);
Values(30,29,34,39,44);
Values(20,49,54,59,64);
```

How can I implement this simple math operation in this text file to get the above result as the output? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('text.txt')]
output = open('a.txt', 'w')

for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    # subtract 10 from all of the components in the first column
    line[0] = int(line[0]) - 10
    # subtract 1 from all of the components in the rest of the columns
    line[1:] = [int(n) - 1 for n in line[1:]]
    output.write('Values({},{},{},{},{});\n'.format(*line))

output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are reading a CSV file. It will be a lot easier to use pandas library to process the file.

```
import pandas as pd

# read the CSV file with space as delimiter
df = pd.read_csv('the.txt', delimiter=' ', header = None)
df.head()

# there are two spaces, so a the number of columns is twice
# remove the columns with NaN values
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df.head()

# subtract the column one by 10
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x - 10)
df.head()

# subtract the rest of the columns by 1
df[[2,4,6,8]] = df[[2,4,6,8]].apply(lambda x: x -1)
df.head()

# convert the dataframe to tuples
records = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_records(index=False)]

# Write the records to the the file
with open('a.txt','w') as outfile: 
    for record in records:
        outfile.write('Values{};\n'.format(record))
```

Comment: The file has one or more whitespaces as delimiter. You can use `delim_whitespace = True` or `sep = "\s+"` in this case. And what's wrong with `df -= 1``?

Comment: @Mr.T thanks for the suggestion regard delim_whitespace. What do you mean by df-=1 ???

Comment: `df.apply()` uses an internal loop, while `df +=` uses the vectorized numpy approach and is therefore much faster. Having said that `apply` has afaik an optimization strategy internally to vectorize operations if possible.